# PyDev: ImportError when trying to call user-defined Java Method using Jython in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, import, pydev, jython, importerror

My question is similar to [ImportErrorCmd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7824968/1186038) but I'm using Windows and trying to run this DAMN thing in PyDev Eclipse. I know how to get it to work on cmd but not in Eclipse.

**QUESTION**

Anyway, so here I am trying to get this example @ [ImportErrorSimpleExample](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3596098/1186038) **to work** (the solution there didn't work for me). In Eclipse, I made a Java project with this code: (link -> *C:\Users\compski\workspace\test\src\test\Greeter.java*)

```
package test;

public class Greeter {

private String msg;

  public Greeter() {
     msg = "Hello, ";
  }

  public void greet(String name) {
     System.out.println(msg + name);
  }

}
```

In Eclipse also, I made a PyDev Project with the Jython code called me.py: (link -> *C:\Users\compski\workspace\Jython\Test\me.py*)

```
from test import Greeter

g = Greeter()
g.greet("yours truly")
```

**Attempts to fix "ImportError" but failed:**

1) I tried adding my java code to PYTHONPATH (C:\Users\compski\workspace\test\src\test\Greeter.java and C:\Users\compski\workspace\test\src\test) as in here -> [Proposed Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3599146/1186038) . Still didn't work

2) I set my Java project to PyDev project (rightclick Java project -> PyDev -> Set as Pydev Project but I don't have any "bin folders". I then also project referenced my Java Project containing the Greeter.java to my PyDev project as in here -> [Proposed solution 2](http://pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html). Still didn't work

3) 1 guy from the chat at SO told me that I need to "you need to add directories, jars from which java will look for classes that is you give it c:\foo\bar\bazand import zyxxy.Frobnicator then it looks for c:\foo\bar\baz\xyzzy\Frobnicator" but I don't think I fully understand what he meant cause it sounds like what I did at 1)

4) ......Your answer?

Comment: You say that it works on the CLI; what did you do there?

Comment: On CMD prompt? .. I basically compiled the java file on cmd prompt (using javac Greeter.java). Then navigating to the same directory as the Greeter.class, I ran Jython (on cmd) .. importing and calling the Java methods went perfectly fine

Comment: What command did you use? How was Jython installed? Was it the standalone Jython jar? Or have you installed Jython to your system?

Comment: @IntrepidBrit 
On CMD, I typed "javac Greeter.java". On the same directory, I typed "jython". Then I typed "import Greeter g = Greeter()
g.greet("yours truly")" and it worked  

Im using Jython 2.5.3 - the installer version @ (http://www.jython.org/downloads.html) installed in my system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now that we have real file names here: given the `PYTHONPATH` of `C:\Users\compski\workspace\test\src\test`, after you do `from test import Greeter`, it will try to find the `Greeter.class` in the each entry of the `PYTHONPATH`; that is it tries to find `C:\Users\compski\workspace\test\src\test\test\Greeter.class` and `C:\Users\compski\workspace\test\src\test\Greeter.java\test\Greeter.class`, neither of which exists.

Instead, in Eclipse if I remember correctly you can add a **project** to the `PYTHONPATH`, this could be preferred for testing in the IDE - thus just add your `test` project as such in the PYTHONPATH. Another option is to add the directory from which `test\Greeter.class` is found; that is in Eclipse this should be `C:\Users\compski\workspace\test\bin` - that is by default the Java-natured projects compile files from `src` to the (hidden) `bin` folder within the project.

Finally if the error is about GreeterClass not found in `test`, do notice that [`test`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/test.html) is a builtin python module name (though IIRC Jython does not have a module by that name).

Comment: +1 the key thing that solved it was 'C:\Users\compski\workspace\test\target\bin' (stupid target folder hid the bin) thank you!